# Struct Pointers Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student

{
    char name[50];
    int St_No;
    float mark[10];
};

int main()
{
    int entrynumber=0;
    int r=0;

    while(r != 1)
    {
        printf("choose one of the following options\n");
        printf("1-Introduce new student\n");
        printf("2-Introduce new mark\n");
        printf("3-Print report of all students\n");
        printf("4-Exit\n");
        char givenname[50];
        int option;
        scanf("%d",&option);
        int n,i,e=0,j=0;
        struct student *St[50], Stu[50];
        St[50] = &Stu[50];

        switch(option)
        {
        case 1:
            entrynumber;
            printf("Enter name of student\n");
            scanf("%s",(*St[entrynumber]).name);
            printf("\nEnter student Number\n"); 
            scanf("%d",&(*St[entrynumber]).St_No);
            entrynumber++;                        
            int noofstudents = entrynumber;       
            break;   

                                           |
```

I cut the rest out

OK so i get seg fault in this line here

```
scanf("%s",(*St[entrynumber]).name);
```

the `scanf` works when i put it in, it just gives a seg fault

can anyone help me pls?

Comment: You've never allocated any memory for your pointers to point to.

Comment: `St[50] = &Stu[50];` accesses both arrays out of bounds (and invokes *undefined behavior*)

Comment: You never check whether your `scanf` was successful.

Comment: `entrynumber;` does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
St[50] = &Stu[50];
```

is not the way to set all the pointers in `St` to point to the corresponding elements of `Stu`. You need a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    St[i] = &Stu[i];
}
```

BTW, `(*St[entrynumber]).name)` is usually written as `St[entrynumber]->name`.

There's really no need for the array of pointers at all. You can just use `Stu[entrynumber].name` and `&Stu[entrynumber].St_No` in your `scanf()` calls.

And don't forget that `%s` in `scanf()` just reads a single word. If you try to enter a first and last name, it won't work. You probably should read a whole line with `fgets()` (and don't forget to remove the newline at the end).

Comment: The last part of the answer may give a wrong impression about scanf() that it does not support reading in a whole line.

Comment: @machine_1 I know you can use `%[^\n]`, I don't want to encourage it....

Comment: THANK YOU!! i did it without pointers but the assignment said to use pointers. and i couldn't get it right.